# Sequences of flips and flops

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I'm having trouble understanding the definitions involved in sequences of flips and flops.  Suppose that one performs a $K_X +D$ flip.  It is understood that $-(K_X+D)$ is relatively ample, and that after the flip the new pair $K_Y+D'$ is relatively ample.  How then does one iterate this procedure?  It seems that to continue with another flip one needs the inverse of this divisor to be relatively ample.

Comment: After a flip one considers a different contraction, i.e.,  the relative ampleness is with respect to different morphisms.